# NSView inside an NSPopover: Converting Coordinates

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nspopover

#### Context

Let `P` be an NSPopover and `view` be an NSView that is a subview contained within `P`.

#### What I Need

I want to take the frame of `view` and convert it to the *screen's* coordinate system. Normally, you would do that like this:

```
NSRect frameRelativeToWindow = [self convertRect:self.frame relativeToView:nil]; 
[self.window convertRectToScreen:frameRelativeToWindow];
```

However, because `view` is in an NSPopover, its `window` property is nil and the above method will return NSZeroRect: [0, 0, 0, 0]

So, how can I get my view's frame in screen coordinates if the view is in an NSPopover?

### Notes:

1. The NSPopover IS onscreen and visible.
2. The view whose frame I am trying to convert to screen coordinates is not a direct subview of the NSPopover or its contentView. The view in question is actually a custom NSView within an NSTableCellView within an NSTableView within an NSScrollView within an NSClipView. The clipView is a direct subview of the NSPopover's contentView.
3. In a normal NSWindow, you can take any subview and call `[self window]` to get the containing NSWindow object. Doing that in a popover, however, returns nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code assumes, that you have

- a NSViewController subclass that manages the popover view
- the view controller implements `NSPopoverDelegate`

As hamstergene pointed out, the popover's window won't be available until it is shown.
When the `popoverWillShow:` delegate method gets called, your popover view's window should be an instance of `_NSPopoverWindow` (and not `nil`).

```
- (void)popoverWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSWindow* popOverWindow = self.view.window;
    NSRect popoverRectInScreenCoords = [popOverWindow convertRectToScreen:self.view.frame];
    NSLog(@"Popover Rect in Screen Coords:%@", NSStringFromRect(popoverRectInScreenCoords));
}
```

**Update**
Bryan (the OP) posted a solution to his problem in the comments.
The issue wasn't `NSPopover` itself. The actual reason for the `nil` window for some of his subviews was `NSTableView`, which releases non-visible `NSTableCellViews`.
As a workaround he implemented `viewDidMoveToWindow` in his custom `NSTableCellView` subclass. When `viewDidMoveToWindow:` gets called, the table cell view already has a window that can be used to perform coordinate conversion.

Comment: Yea, I get what you guys are saying. But using -popoverWillShow: is not an option for me. The popover IS SHOWING already. I have several NSViews in a normal subview-superview hierarchy in the popover. What I'm telling you is that when I call -window on any of those NSViews, I get nil. In a normal NSWindow, you can call -window on any NSView in the hierarchy and get back the containing Window object. That does not appear to work for NSPopover. How do I work around that fact?

Comment: I replicated the setup you described in your updated question using a view based table view with a data source (not Cocoa Bindings). I am getting a window for each of my custom NSTableCellView subclasses as long as the cell view is currently displayed. The table view releases non-visible views. Maybe you are trying to obtain a window from a nil-table view cell? You can force NSTableView to return a cell view instance by passing "YES" to [NSTableView rowViewAtRow: makeIfNecessary:] as last parameter.

Comment: That last comment got me thinking and I solved it. The issue was a race condition --- window was nil on the subview because NSTableView removes/re-adds the NSTableCellViews as the table reloads. I moved the logic to -viewDidMoveToWindow within my NSTableCellView subclass and it worked perfectly. That code simply tells the subview within my cellView that it can now test to see if it's under the cursor. If you'll write that up as the answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Done. Thanks for posting the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach for calculating screen coordinates is correct (just don't forget to convert view's frame coordinates to window's base coordinates first using `convertRect:self.frame toView:nil`).

The problem is that the window is not created until the popover is displayed. Before that, there is no way to find the view's screen coordinates, because it is not on a screen.

If waiting for display is too late for you, catch `popoverWillShow:` delegate method (or the corresponding notification), which fires right before displaying the popover when the window is already created and positioned.

Comment: The popover is definitely onscreen when I'm doing this. Essentially, some NSViews inside the popover get moved around and I want to hit-test to see if they are now underneath the mouse cursor. I'm calling [NSEvent mouseLocation] to get the cursor point; now I just need the rect of my NSView within the popover converted to screen coordinates so I can compare. But if I NSLog self.window, I get nil; the window property of the view is not assigned, even when the popover is onscreen.

Comment: As for converting to window coordinates: I'm doing that as well. Edited to clarify.