# Mac: How to add small view on hover event of window's maximize button in Mac OS X using Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is for Mac OS X Cocoa application.

Please see below image:

[image]

I want to show this kind of view on mouse hover of the maximize button of the window using Cocoa.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325479/nsview-inside-an-nspopover-converting-coordinates

Comment: Is the image included in the question a screenshot from a real application? If so, could you tell me what it's called? I found this SO question while looking for a utility exactly like the one in the screenshot!